# Get the current serial protocol config of a TU30-D400 Series GPS

Tags: gps, nmea

I have an old Jupiter GPS from the TU30-D400 Series

When I put its 7th to the GND, I can force it to use the NMEA Protocol with a 4800 baud rate.

The thing is that GPS is used by a pretty old tide gauge, and it has its own serial configuration.

How can I know what kind of config does it have when I'm on the NMEA Protocol ( Pin 7 to GND )

http://www.sander-electronic.de/datasheet/gps/NAVMAN_Jupiter_11_Datasheet.pdf